# Safari on Windows - CSS background size and position with SVG gradient

Tags: windows, svg, background, safari

No matter what I try, I can't get this SVG gradient to work properly in the most recent Safari (5.1.7) on Windows:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 1920 200">  
    <linearGradient id="g186" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0" y2="200">  
        <stop stop-color="#0A306A" offset="0"/><stop stop-color="#030C1B" offset="1"/>  
    </linearGradient>  
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="1920" height="200" fill="url(#g186)" />  
</svg>`
```

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/wumnb/1/ (Note that the browser may throw an XSS warning because of the base64-encoded SVG)

When I include `-webkit-background-size: 100% 200px;` with and/or without the `-webkit-`, it re-sizes the SVG, but it looks significantly lighter than every other browser; almost as if it was cropping a full-page version of the SVG from the top to 200px from the top.

I've tried both answers from the [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9185434/using-svg-as-background-image) two [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11768364/svg-scaling-issues-in-safari) I could find, but neither is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that `preserveAspectRatio="none"` needs to be `preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMax meet"` with viewbox set to the wanted dimensions. Sadly, this doesn't allow for percentages, but it's better than nothing.

[W3 documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#PreserveAspectRatioAttribute) for preserveAspectRatio.

**EDIT**: Upon playing with this more, I've discovered that background position is really weird in Safari. The xM(in|id|ax)yM(in|id|ax) part of the `preserveAspectRatio` seem to determine where the SVG will go on the page, rather than do what's described on W3.

It appears (to me at least) that xMidYMax is the equivalent of `background-position: center bottom;` and xMinyMin is the equivalent of `background-position: center top;`