# SVG Scaling Issue in IE9

Tags: html, css, svg, internet-explorer-9, image-resizing

Having issues using small svg in IE9. It get's chopped off on the right/is not centered:

[image: screenshot] (Supposed to be a "X")

My SVG:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.4, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 364.786 364.786" enable-background="new 0 0 364.786 364.786"
     xml:space="preserve" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin none">
<polygon fill="#999999" points="300.988,0 182.388,118.618 63.768,0.015 0,63.745 118.639,182.376 0.015,301.018 63.745,364.786 
    182.395,246.127 301.045,364.771 364.786,300.988 246.15,182.371 364.771,63.742 "/>
</svg>
```

I removed *width* and *height* and have *viewbox* and *preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin none"* though...

http://jsfiddle.net/dzCL2/12/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your preserveAspectRatio value is invalid, and should be ignored by the browser:

```
preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin none"
```

The default value of `xMidYMid meet` will be used when rendering in this case.

Refer to the [SVG 1.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#PreserveAspectRatioAttribute) for the syntax details. It's possible that IE treats the value as partially valid, applying the `xMinYMin` part only, that would cause a left-aligned image. Using correct syntax should hopefully fix the problem.

Comment: great! that worked... I copied the invalid value from here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11780399/395035

Answer (score 1):

The correct setting which worked for me in Safari to avoiding proportional scaling:

```
<svg ... preserveAspectRatio="none">

</svg>
```